# Unit test a Frontend Page Reload

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, frontend, karma-runner

I have a Web Frontend that persists its state using localStorage.

I.e. the same page is shown to the user upon page reload.

I'd now like to unit test that the page shown after a reload is the same than the page shown before the reload.

Doing `window.location.reload()` wihtin a jasmine test within the karma runner with PhantomJS throws me an Error 'Some of your tests did a full page reload!'.

Is there a way to have an automated test for a page reload? I'm open to switch test framework, test runner, and test browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have an e2e test suite started? This seems out of the scope of unit testing basic functionality.

Comment: @TomA yep seems to be that you are right, I actually found the answer to my quesion, see my reply

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The tests you are describing are **functional tests** rather than unit tests.

You need a test runner that supports functional tests.

Karma doesn't support functional tests but e.g. CasperJS does.

Comment: Of course you can perform functional tests in karma.  It take just a wee bit of work, but all you have to do is compile your html, linked with a scope, run scope.digest(), and you have an object that responds almost perfectly. Remember to trigger appropriate events when setting up tests with UI interactions, but aside from that, its just fine.

Comment: @wizardwerdna, Appreciate your comment, but can you create an actual answer to this question with sample code? It sounds like you're talking about an Angularjs-specific solution.